# Using PHP to gather an image at a specified URL and storing it into a database

Tags: php, image, curl, screen-scraping, scraper

Generally, I am looking to input a URL and then import the image at that URL into a database.

Here is some code that has me close, but alternatives are welcomed.

If I try to store $image into a database as a BLOB, it presents an error.

```
<?php



class wSpider
{
    var $ch; /// going to used to hold our cURL instance
    var $html; /// used to hold resultant html data
    var $binary; /// used for binary transfers
    var $url; /// used to hold the url to be downloaded

    function wSpider()
    {
        $this->html = "http:/";
        $this->binary = 0;
        $this->url = "";
    }


    function fetchPage($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
        if (isset($this->url)) {
            $this->ch = curl_init(); /// open a cURL instance
            curl_setopt ($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // tell cURL to return the data
            curl_setopt ($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url); /// set the URL to download
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); /// Follow any redirects
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, $this->binary); /// tells cURL if the data is binary data or not
            $this->html = curl_exec($this->ch); // pulls the webpage from the internet
            curl_close ($this->ch); /// closes the connection
        }
    }
}

$mySpider = new wSpider(); //// creates a new instance of the wSpider
$mySpider->binary = 1; /// turns on the binary transfer mode
$image = $mySpider->fetchPage("http://static.php.net/www.php.net/images/php.gif");

?>
```

Comment: which error does it represent?

Comment: Put four spaces before each line of code so SO formats it properly.

Comment: please edit your question and format your code :D 
(select the code section and click on the brackets)

Comment: You need to format your code to be more readable before you can expect help with it. Use the text editor's buttons to do it.

Comment: there is no formatting required as there are not so hard functions. However, he didn't tell us which "error" does SQL represent

Comment: Thanks for formatting but it might be useful to know which database engine you are using, the table structure and the error. Aside from that, there is always a debate about storing binary data inside the database vs storing a pointer in the database to a file in the file system.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need all that stuff.

You can do: `$image = file_get_contents($url);`

And then `pdo::prepare("INSERT INTO img (?, ?)");`